# Where is time.py located?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I tried to search in all directories listed in `sys.path` but I couldn't find any sort of file named `time.py`. Where is it located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `time` module is a C extension:

```
>>> import time
>>> time
<module 'time' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/time.so'>
```

It could also display as:

```
<module 'time' (built-in)>
```

depending on your platform, Python version, and compile-time options.

As such, to look at the implementation you'll have to look at the [`timemodule.c` C source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/429acfbef89c/Modules/timemodule.c).

It is a C extension because it wraps many [C stdlib `time.h` functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) in Python-friendly wrappers.

Comment: Ok I understood, I tried your code and I got the second output. After that I tried to look up in the folder `/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/` but there is no `time.so` file, where is it located?

Comment: @antox: what platform are you on?

Comment: @antox: if it says 'built-in' it was linked into your Python binary and is not a separate dynamic library. There is then no separate file object to look at. Not that there is much to see, the C source code won't be there.